# QMediaPlayer.play() doesn't work if I call a function with it

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer

I'm creating an Audio player with Qt and I'm implementing that when I load a song it start automaticaly, but when I call the function for start the song and calculate the duration, the song doesn't start. I used the debug and when I reach the play function debug stopped with end-stepping-range. I have also tried to emit a signal but nothing to do, the song start only if I press the Play button.

Here there is the code

```
void AudioPlayer::loadClicked()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Select an audio file", "C:/Users/belli/Music" ,"File Mp3 (*.mp3)");

    if(!filename.isEmpty())
    {
        qDebug("%s", filename.toLatin1().constData());
        player.setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filename));
        this->volumeSliderMoved();
        QFileInfo fi(filename);
        QString name = fi.fileName();
        ui->label->setText(name);
        this->playClicked();
    }
}

void AudioPlayer::playClicked()
{
    player.play();
    songLength = player.duration();
    ui->horizontalSliderPosition->setRange(0, songLength);
}

void AudioPlayer::stopClicked()
{
    player.stop();
    ui->horizontalSliderPosition->setValue(0);
}

void AudioPlayer::playerPositionChanged(qint64 pos)
{
   ui->horizontalSliderPosition->setValue(pos);
   if(pos == songLength)
       this->stopClicked();
}

void AudioPlayer::volumeSliderMoved()
{
    player.setVolume(ui->horizontalSliderVolume->value());
}

void AudioPlayer::positionSliderMoved()
{
    player.setPosition((quint64) ui->horizontalSliderPosition->value());
}
```

And the connects

```
ui(new Ui::AudioPlayer)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButtonLoad, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(loadClicked()));
    connect(ui->pushButtonPlay, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(playClicked()));
    connect(ui->pushButtonStop, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(stopClicked()));
    connect(ui->horizontalSliderVolume, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), SLOT(volumeSliderMoved()));
    connect(ui->horizontalSliderPosition, SIGNAL(sliderReleased()), SLOT(positionSliderMoved()));

    connect(&player, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), SLOT(playerPositionChanged(qint64)));
}
```

Comment: I'd check the cyclic bond between `playerPositionChanged` and `positionSliderMoved`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing that [`setMedia`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#setMedia) works asynchronously. That is, it returns with no guarantee that the media file is loaded, from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#setMedia):

> This function returns **immediately** after recording the specified source
>   of the media. It **does not wait for the media to finish loading** and does not check for errors. **Listen for the [`mediaStatusChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#mediaStatusChanged) and [`error()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#error) signals to be notified** when the media is loaded and when an error occurs during loading.

This means that when you call `this->playClicked();` after you've called `player.setMedia(...);`, there is a big chance that the media file has not been loaded yet, and the call to [`player.duration()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#duration-prop) fails (it does not return the real duration of the media file you are trying to play). So, you end up with your duration slider having a range of `(0, 0)`, and this causes a call to `player.stop()` later since you think that you have reached the end of your media file. . .

To solve this, You need to follow what is written in the docs. Make sure not to advance to your `playClicked` slot unless you make sure your media file is fully loaded. You can do that by replacing your:

```
this->playClicked();
```

With something like this:

```
connect(&player, &QMediaPlayer::mediaStatusChanged,
        this, [&](QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status){
    if(status == QMediaPlayer::LoadedMedia) playClicked();
});
```